# More efficient way of iterating over every small square in big square array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm in my first few months of learning to code in C through a high school program. Someone recently mentioned to me that there's often a way to make code more efficient and I think I have a problem that could be made more efficient. I'm not sure how but I have a hunch that it could be made faster.

We're given a 2D square array of integers with row and col size n. We have subsquares within the 2D square array with row and col size s. We can always assume that s will evenly divide n. I've written the following code to iterate over each subsquare

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
int **grid;
int s, i, j, k, l;

// reading in inputs, other processing

for (i = 0; i < n; i += s) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j += s) {
        for (k = 0; k < s; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < s; l++) {
                printf("%d \n", grid[i + k][j + l]);
            }
        }
        printf("next subsquare: \n");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've got 4 nested for loops and I feel like it's a bit messy to have it in this format. Is there a better way to do this? Later on I might be summing each subsquare or performing some other operation with each subsquare.

Comment: While you could flatten the loop, it wouldn't improve efficiency as your compiler is already doing this under the hood anyway.  If you think about it, you need to access every square to do this - so if the loop runs the same number of times as there are squares, you've already reached peak efficiency.

Comment: Do you mean s will evenly divide n, rather than evenly divide n x n? For example, if n is 6, is s allowed to be 4?

Comment: @IanAbbott Ah yes, I meant that. Thank you for pointing that out. I'll update my question.

Comment: You still need to access all possible subsquares, but you can do it in [a pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) which will improve locality of reference.

Comment: Though if this code is representative, then there's little point in optimising, as runtime will likely be dominated by `printf` I/O.

Comment: You could optimize this by printing the data to an array of strings, then call printf only on row basis. Or better yet, get rid of printf entirely and call the console API directly. Or better yet, don't worry about optimizing some console junk, because in the real world outside school, nobody writes programs like that anyway.

Comment: You said "later I might perform other operation". Lets focus on that; i.e. drop the requiremt to do it subsquare by subsquare, because that is only caused by the printf. You can create an `array[n/s][n/s]` with a result value for each of the subsquares. (Maybe more such array for each subsquare specific variable.) Then you can loop over the whole array in 2D, i.e. only two for loops. Calculate the result array member (the one to update) from the coordinates of the current input value. Number of nested loops reduced. Total operations identical. Locality of data will be worse.